# jQuery: check if mouse is over an element

Tags: jquery

I'm working with the following scenario:
I have an image map with hotspots. When you mouse over an `<area>` on the image map, shows a `<div class="info-panel">`.  This div overlaps the `<area>`, so the div is hidden on mouseleave of `<div class="info-panel">`.

This mostly works, but on the odd occasion, for example if you go ballistic and move the mouse around too fast, the div stays up. I think it may be in the small instances where the `<area>` and the `<div>` intersect. I wouldn't worry about it, only the client has pointed it out as a bug.

The only foolproof way I can think to fix this is to check on mouse move if an info-window is visible. If one is, then check whether the mouse is currently over it -- if it's not, then hide it.  This will ensure that an info window is never visible if a mouse is not over it.

My question is: how do I check whether the current mouse position is over an info window? Bearing in mind that this is for the exception rather than the rule, and I don't know **for sure** whether an info window is visible or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you mouseout have a timer that runs after 1 second for example, that closes all windows.

When you mouseover be sure to remove that timer... so the timer is only set when you mouseout.

Something like:

```
var timer; 
$(".window").mouseout(function(){
    $(".window").hide(); // regular hide

    // run the same thing after 1 second
    // to catch windows that are still open
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".window").hide(); // regular hide
    }, 1000); // 1 second
});

// be sure to remove the timer when you mouseover
$(".window").mouseover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);

    // other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `mouseover` try `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` as event handlers.

Comment: I'm using mouseover for the area, and mouseleave for the div... using mouseenter on the area doesn't make a difference here unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function show_info (thelink,info_panel) {   
    var timer; 
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(info_panel).stop(true, true).fadeIn('normal');
    }, 300); 
    $(thelink).mouseout(function(){ clearTimeout(timer); });
}

function hide_info (resim) {
    $(info_panel).stop(true, true).fadeOut('normal');
}
```

And the html code should be:

```
<a href="#" id="thelink" onmouseover="show_tipbox('#thelink','#info_panel');">The link</a>
<div id="info_panel" onmouseout="hide_tipbox('#info_panel');">Info Panel Content</div>
```